# NullPointerException from the com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.license

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cloudbees

After upgrading my jenkins install on ubuntu using ubuntu packages, I'm getting an error with the cloudbees licence plugin.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.license.BootHook.innerOnLoaded(BootHook.java:59)
at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.license.BootHook.onLoaded(BootHook.java:49)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:845)
at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:77)
at hudson.WebAppMain$2.run(WebAppMain.java:214)
```

My jenkins version is 1.492

If I disable the plugin, that works, but I cannot see some project that are in folders.
How can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

A change in core affected the plugin.

Briefly, there is a conflict between versions of Bouncy Castle in core and the plugin. As the plugin has to support a wide range of Jenkins versions, it includes a version of Bouncy Castle, and requests that this be loaded in an isolated classloader... Under certain circumstances core will resolve the classloaders differently when looking for extensions, and the extension can end up resolving a different version of Bouncy Castle... which results in the extension (free-license-plugin) not being found, and the corresponding NPE.

We fixed this issue a couple of days after 1.490 was released. The fix is in cloudbees-license 3.5 and free-license 3.2 (also in nectar-license 3.3 - but that is only of relevance if you are running any of the Jenkins Enterprise plugins)

To get a borked system back to working here is the set of steps to follow:

1. Stop Jenkins (if you haven't already)
2. Remove the following directories `$JENKINS_HOME/plugins/cloudbees-license`, `$JENKINS_HOME/plugins/free-license` and if present `$JENKINS_HOME/plugins/nectar-license`
3. Remove the following files `$JENKINS_HOME/plugins/cloudbees-license.hpi`,  `$JENKINS_HOME/plugins/cloudbees-license.jpi`, `$JENKINS_HOME/plugins/free-license.hpi`,  `$JENKINS_HOME/plugins/cloudbees-license.jpi`, and if present `$JENKINS_HOME/plugins/nectar-license.hpi` or `$JENKINS_HOME/plugins/nectar-license.jpi` (*Note:* normally there will only be either the `.hpi` *or* the `.jpi` file present. Which is present depends on what version of Jenkins was installed when you downloaded the plugin originally. It doesn't matter which.
4. Download the latest versions of the plugins that you removed: (*Note:* only download the `nectar-license` plugin if you removed it in steps 2 and 3)

   - [cloudbees-license](http://jenkins-updates.cloudbees.com/download/plugins/cloudbees-license/3.5/cloudbees-license.hpi)
   - [free-license](http://jenkins-updates.cloudbees.com/download/plugins/free-license/3.2/free-license.hpi)
   - [nectar-license](http://jenkins-updates.cloudbees.com/download/plugins/nectar-license/3.3/nectar-license.hpi) (only if needed)

   It is up to you whether you rename the `.hpi` to `.jpi`. Jenkins will pick it up either way, but for longer-term compatibility I would recommend renaming them to the `.jpi` extension.
5. Start Jenkins
6. Do the [funky-chicken dance](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DH2gGu8cGHY)

Comment: Just one thing to add: if Jenkins otherwise starts up OK and you can get to Plugin Manager, then it may work to simply update the *-license plugins from there and restart.

Comment: My tests showed the instance refuses to start... Though I might have been doing something wrong... Hence the "always works" answer (even if it forces the CLI usage)